# Prove that a Möbius transformation $T$ sends the imaginary line to the circle $\{z: |z|=2\}$,

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Problem**

Let $T:\overline{\mathbb C} \to \overline{\mathbb C}$ be a Möbius transformation such that $T(1+2i)=1$, $T(-1+2i)=4$ and $|T(0)|=2$. Show that $|T(bi)|=2$ for all $b \in \mathbb R$.

The exercise asks me to show that the imaginary line is mapped to the circle centered at $0$ of radius $2$. I've tried to solve it in the most basic way, which is to express $T(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$,, solve for $a,b,c,d$ from the information given and try to get to $|T(bi)|=(T(bi)\overline{T(bi)})^{\frac{1}{2}}=2$.

I am still struggling with the operations but I wanted to know: Is there a simpler way or an alternative solution to this one? I would appreciate if someone could suggest another solution using properties of Möbius transformations, or cross-ratio, symmetric points or whatever it is useful in the theory of Möbius transformations to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Möbius transformations map straight lines and circles to straight lines and circles. Also, Möbius transformations preserve symmetry in the sense that if $z,w$ are two points symmetric with respect to a circle or straight line $C$, then $Tz$ and $Tw$ are symmetric with respect to $T(C)$.

The points $1+2i$ and $-1+2i$ are symmetric with respect to the imaginary axis. So the points $1$ and $4$ are symmetric with respect to $C = T(i\mathbb{R})$. And $C$ contains at least one point with modulus $2$.

There is only one straight line in the plane with respect to which $1$ and $4$ are symmetric, the line $\operatorname{Re} z = \frac{5}{2}$. That line contains no point with modulus $2$. So $C$ must be a circle. The midpoint of that circle must lie on the straight line through $1$ and $4$, so on the real axis, and it cannot lie between $1$ and $4$. A circle with respect to which $1$ and $4$ are symmetric and whose midpoint is real $> 4$ lies entirely to the right of the line $\operatorname{Re} z = \frac{5}{2}$, so contains no point with modulus $2$. Thus the midpoint $a$ must lie to the left of $1$. Of two such circles $C_{a,r} = \{z : \lvert z-a\rvert^2 = r^2\}$ with $a < 1$ such that $1$ and $4$ are symmetric with respect to $C_{a,r}$, one is entirely contained in the interior of the other. The two points $1$ and $4$ are symmetric with respect to $C_{0,2}$. Therefore $C = C_{0,2}$ is the only such circle containing any point with modulus $2$.

Comment: Your answer is very well written so sorry if I still have some doubts: I don't understand why these affirmations are true (or from where I can deduce them):" The midpoint of that circle must lie on the straight line through $1$ and $4$, so on the real axis, and it cannot lie between $1$ and $4$.", and " Of two such circles $C_{a,r}=\{z:∣z−a∣^2=r^2\}$ with $a<1$ such that $1$ and $4$ are symmetric with respect to $C_{a,r}$, one is entirely contained in the interior of the other." I could follow the rest of the proof steps but I couldn't understand those two.

Comment: Two points $w,w'$ are symmetric with respect to the circle $\lvert z-\mu\rvert^2 = \rho^2$ if and only if they satisfy $(w-\mu)\overline{(w'-\mu)} = \rho^2$ (or one is $\mu$ and the other $\infty$), so they must lie on the same ray emanating from the centre of the circle. For the disjointness of the symmetry-circles, you can calculate, or you can look at the situation when one point is $0$ and the other $\infty$. It's obvious then, and since the symmetry is preserved under Möbius transformations, the general case follows.